# How to Connect Data Points As If Hand-Drawn in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, spline, datapoint

I am trying to connect six Data points in a way as I would do it intuitively by hand. The regular `plot` command gives me a very jagged line because it's only six data points. The `spline` command gets close to were I want to be. However it continues to fit the line before and after. I however would like for it to start with the first data point and to end with the last. Further I would like to avoid the bump shown in the picture attached. For this I would need a higher order polynomial I'd assume.

Can someone help me to connect those data points as one would do it manually? It does not need to be done via the `spline` command.

Minimal Example:

```
clear all, close all, clc
%% Minimal Example

%% Data
x = 2:7;
y = [69, 27, 3, 0.5, 0, 0]

%% Using Regular Plot
plot(x,y)

%% Using Spline
hold on
xx = 0:.25:10;
yy = spline(x,y,xx);
plot(x,y,'o',xx,yy)
```

[image: Data points connected via plot and spline]

[image: Bump]

Comment: just use `xlim` and `ylim` to limit your plot axis

Comment: @AnderBiguri would be an easy way to do it. I am hindered to do so for other reasons not mentioned in the minimal example. Another dataset is in the plot as well

Comment: Then just crop the datapoints from `xx` and `yy` that you dont want....

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I oversaw that option.
Reduces the question to the bump. any ideas on that?

Comment: `xx=xx(xx>min_desired_value && xx<max_desired_value)`. This is a trivial indexing task, you shoudl be able to find documentation on that.

Answer (score 0):

For stopping the spline at the desired beginning and ending I had edit `xx = 2:.25:7` to the desired boundaries 2 to 7. I oversaw that option.

In order to get rid of the bump I edited `yy` with the following `for-loop`. This does the job for me right now.

I'd still be thankful if someone knows how to just connect data points with a more curvy line. Thank you!

```
clear all, close all, clc
%% Minimal Example

%% Data
x = 2:7;
y = [69, 27, 3, 0.5, 0, 0]

%% Using Regular Plot
plot(x,y)

%% Using Spline
hold on
xx = 0:.25:10;
yy = spline(x,y,xx);
i = 1;
xx = 2:.05:7;
yy = spline(x,y,xx);
for i = 1:length(yy)
    if yy(i) < 0.3
        idx = i
        for idx = idx:length(yy)
            yy(idx) = 0.3
            idx = idx + 1
        end
    end
end
plot(xx,yy,'LineWidth',3)
```

Comment: That loop is the same as `idx = find(yy<0.3,1); yy(idx:end)=0.3;`, as far as I can tell.